# Getting full image URL using Glass Mapper without RenderImage

Tags: glass-mapper

```razor
Html.Glass().RenderImage(Model, x => x.Logo, new { mw = 200 }, Editable:true)
```

The code above outputs an `img` tag with the full URL including the hashed parameters.

I want a way to get just the URL (without writing a lot of extra code). 
The purpose of this is to set an inline background image style.

I know the Glass Mapper `Image` class has a `Src` property but that just provides the basic URL without the hashed parameters, so the image would be downloaded full size.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will work for the basic params;

```
@using Sitecore.Resources.Media

<div style="background-image:url(@HashingUtils.ProtectAssetUrl(string.Format("{0}?{1}", Model.Logo.Src, new MediaUrlOptions { MaxWidth = 200 })))">Hello</div>
```